# Payment extension for Apple Pay through Authorize.net on Magento 1

Tags: module, magento-1, authorize.net

Does anybody know of a payment module that supports Apple Pay through Authorize.net for Magento 1? I can find something for PayPal or Magento 2, but not specifically Magento 1 through Authorize.net.

Comment: let us know if you found Apple Pay for Authorize.net because we are finding same.

Comment: I found this link but am not sure how reliable they are in terms of implementation or execution. This is though with Authorize.net https://store.thecommerceshop.com/apple-pay-m1.html